# How to improve performance when rendering <table> in IE 8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, internet-explorer-8

I have a jquery function which adds  tag to first row of table.
I tried using append, however its not working, so i got a solution which is very slow and it somehow gives error "Script on this page is causing internet explorer run slow..."

Function is as

```
 jQuery.fn.fixGridView = function () {
        "use strict";
       // var start = +new Date();  // log start timestamp 
        if (jQuery(this).is('table') && this.find('thead').length === 0) {

            var theadv = "<thead><tr>" + this.find('tbody tr:first').html(); +"</tr></thead>";

            this.find('tbody tr:first').remove();
            var htmlv = this.html();
            this.html(theadv + htmlv);
        }
        //var end = +new Date();  // log end timestamp
       // var diff = end - start;
       // alert(diff);
        return this;
    };
```

Can anybody help me to make this code run faster?

EDIT: I have to use IE..that is the requirement (ie8). 
Edit2: I have created js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4xLzL/

Comment: Step 1: Don't use IE.

Comment: I have to use IE.. It is client requirement

Comment: can you make fiddle please ?\

Comment: It is better suited for [codereview.stackexchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Aron: I have created jsfiddle: check my edit

Comment: It's slow because you're dealing with creating and appending to DOM elements. You're also not "caching" the things you `.find()` for so you're doing more than 1 lookup.

Answer (score 2):

To increase rendering performance you must understand that DOM manipulation (including reflows & repaints) are expensive operations. Your code currently re-creates the entire table with the `<thead>` added the majority of the `<tbody>` content remains the same. This massive "redraw" of the table is highly inefficient. Especially when [in IE 8, where rendering tables is extra slow,](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/2afa46aa-16bb-4e65-be38-a6de19b2b2e9/poor-performance-with-tables-in-internet-explorer-8-standards-mode?forum=iewebdevelopment) you have to modify the DOM as little as possible.

I've refactored your logic to minimize the number of lookups performed to find elements by saving them to a variable to be re-used. Also, removed the `.html('...')` call that re-renders the table, but instead used the [`.prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) function to add the `<thead>` into the `<table>` as the first child.

```
jQuery.fn.fixGridView = function () {
    "use strict";
    var start = +new Date(); // log start timestamp 
    if (this.is('table') && this.children('thead').length === 0) {

        var firstRow = this.children('tbody').children('tr:first');
        var thead = "<thead><tr>" + firstRow.html() + "</tr></thead>";
        firstRow.remove();
        this.prepend(thead);
    }
    var end = +new Date(); // log end timestamp
    var diff = end - start;
    alert(diff);
    return this;
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('table[id*="gvCategories"]').fixGridView();
});
```

Go ahead and test it in IE8: http://jsfiddle.net/amyamy86/4xLzL/7/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the plugin, but with your selector. You only want tables, so modify your selector to be as follows.

```
$('table [id*="gvCategories"]').fixGridView();
```

I also updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4xLzL/1/).